# Setting subnet mask to 255.255.255.255

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address

If I want just 1 device to be on the network, can I set the subnet mask to 255.255.255.255?

For example, the consider the network card configuration

IP   10.0.0.10     mask 255.255.255.255    Gateway 10.0.0.1

10.0.0.10 will be the only device in the network talking to the 10.0.0.1 gateway?
Is there a problem with this configuration?

Comment: A device and a gateway... isn't that two devices?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there's a problem.  Your default gateway needs to be in the same subnet as your device.  By setting the subnet mask to 255.255.255.255, you've told the computer that nothing else is in its subnet.  A more appropriate way to do things would be to set your device IP to 10.0.0.2, your gateway to 10.0.0.1, and your subnet mask to 255.255.255.252.

Answer (score 5):

There are two machines in your subnet pc + gateway, so you should set up at least /30 mask (255.255.255.252) and the proper network of course.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

A device address 32-bit mask cannot have a gateway; it must be routed.  Typically, 32-bit masks are used on loopback addresses.

If you are attempting to have a point-to-point link, you may use a 31-bit mask, per RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links.